# Column filtering not working after applying rowsProcessor in ui-grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have an angular ui grid which has external filters and column filters.
I'm using rowsProcessor while applying external filter and also while resetting the external filter.

I'm using this command for resetting the filters.

```
$scope.gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor( $scope.DisplayAll, 200 );

$scope.DisplayAll = function( renderableRows ){
renderableRows.forEach( function( row ) {
              row.visible = true;

                });
            return renderableRows;
}
```

Once this is done, the grid is populated with all the data but the column filters present in the grid aren't working.
Can anyone explain why this is happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** having a "display all" filter as a rowsProcessor filter does not make a lot of sense, since it will run after every filtering cycle and override everything applied before it.

Here's some further description of the problem:

You have told `DisplayAll` to run at a priority of 200 in the grid, which means all filters applied before it (which includes the built-in column filters) are being overriden with `row.visible = true;`.

If a column filter (which is being run at priotiry 100) determines that a row should not be displayed it will set `row.visible = false;`.  **After** that happens, when `DisplayAll` encounters that row, it will change `row.visible = true;` thus ignoring the column filter.

Any rowsProcessor filter that is added should account for previously applied  filters by doing something such as `row.visible = row.visible && <new condition>`.